Setup Hetzner VPS to use another Hetzner VPS as internet gateway - `Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway`
I have two VPSs on hetnzner, they are both on a public network and a shared private network.
A = 10.0.0.3
B = 10.0.0.2

I'm trying to setup A as an internet gateway for B
So on A I ran:
publicInterface="eth0"
privateInterface="enp7s0"

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING \
  -o "$publicInterface" \
  -j MASQUERADE

sudo iptables -A FORWARD \
  -i "$privateInterface" \
  -o "$publicInterface" \
  -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD \
  -i "$publicInterface" \
  -o "$privateInterface" \
  -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED \
  -j ACCEPT

And then on B I ran:
   sudo ip route del default
   sudo ip route add default via 10.0.0.3 dev enp7s0

The second command returns an error of Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
What am I doing wrong here?
ip addr for private interface on B:
root@debian-4gb-hel1-3:~# ip addr | grep enp7s0 -A 10
3: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:00:00:fe:12:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.2/32 brd 10.0.0.2 scope global dynamic enp7s0
       valid_lft 85895sec preferred_lft 85895sec
    inet6 fe80::8400:ff:fefe:12cd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I can ping the IP with no issue:
root@debian-4gb-hel1-3:~# ping 10.0.0.3
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.927 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.419 ms

root@debian-4gb-hel1-3:~# ip route show
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.0.1 dev enp7s0 
10.0.0.1 dev enp7s0 scope link 
172.31.1.1 dev eth0 scope link 


According to https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7001170

Check the IP address and subnet mask of the network interface, and
make sure the gateway IP address is within the same subnet. Refer to
diagnostics steps for more information.

This likely seems to be the issue as the interface shows 10.0.0.2/32 which does not seem to match the subnet mentioned in the Hetzner admin which is 10.0.0.0/24.

Do you know for sure that the two servers are on the same Ethernet network? (For example, does an arping reach the other server?) This isn't guaranteed with modern cloud™ hosting.

arping ... does not seem to respond with a successful response - it times out. So it looks like you are correct.

According to your output, your private network is configured with a /32 netmask - which means no other IP is directly reachable except your own IP!
And the error is returned because the gateway IP must be directly reachable over an interface route. So you have two options now:

change the subnet of the private network to include each other ( f.e. /24 or /29 )
add an interface route for this specific IP. This already has been done for the IP 10.0.0.1, and you would need to add another for your other IP (10.0.0.2 or .3 ) For example:

ip route add 10.0.0.2 dev enp7s0

you would need to add the interface route for each other on both VPS, of course

https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nat-for-cloud-networks
I had to do the following step in the hetzner admin (with the correct ip replaced). I'm still not sure why it's required though.

Step 2 - Adding the route to the Network In order for our setup to
work properly, we need to add the following route to the Network:
Destination: 0.0.0.0/0 Gateway: 10.0.0.2
The gateway should be the IP address of the NAT server on which you
configure masquerading.

This also seems to have a limitation that it sets the default gateway for the entire network as opposed to just the particular VPS I want, as I would potentially want more than one default gateway while still having a shared private network between VPSs.
I think this (https://docs.hetzner.com/cloud/networks/faq/#why-do-packets-with-source-ips-outside-of-my-network-prefix-get-dropped) explains the behaviour:

The gateways behind a Network implement a concept called "strict
unicast reverse path forwarding" (strict uRPF). This means that the
gateway will check the source IP of every packet against the routing
table of the Network. If the best route for this source IP does not
point back to the server that sent the packet, the gateway will not
forward it.

